# In a rectangular waveguide, how can one determine if any propagation modes exist?

Tags: electromagnetism, microwaves, waveguide

I'm currently studying microwave engineering, and I came across the query mentioned above. I know that rectangular waveguides use TE(m,n),TE and TM modes, but I do not understand how these modes came into being. Can someone please help me?

Comment: This is text-book stuff. Which text books have you checked? One example could be Pozar *Microwave Engineering*, but there are many others. Briefly, you solve Maxwell's equations with perfect electric conductor boundary conditions at the walls of the waveguide, and with scattering boundary conditions at the boundaries where you don't have walls. You look for propagating time-harmonic solutions

Comment: Propagation modes exists if propagation constant is real-valued (for PEC boundaries). Complex-valued propagation constant means that waves are evanescent, i.e. they are vanishing as they propagate

Answer (score 0):

See Chapter $8$ section $3$ called *Waveguides* in John Jackson's *Classical Electromagnetism* which discusses exactly what you desire. Shortly, these modes come from solving a wave PDE per certain boundary conditions. Then, depending on the waveguide dimensions, only certain solutions (modes) are admissible for the waveguide.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).